# Accidentally pressing TouchID/Power button on MacBookPro

Tags: macbook

I am a bad typist with fat fingers and (too) often I lightly hit the Touch ID/Power Button. This brings up a screen asking for my password - time consuming and distracting. By sheer frustration I deleted the password from my Mac so that now I can log back on by just hitting the return key. Lack of protection and worse, I cannot use Touch ID at all. Is there a better solution short of becoming a better typist?
MacBook Pro 16" 2019, Sonoma 14.2.1 (but the same was happening with Monterey)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I accidentally hit Touch ID and it brings up the lock screen, I usually just touch it again to Touch ID may way back in (I have "Use Touch ID to unlock my Mac" enabled in "Settings > Touch ID & Password"). Would that work for you?

Comment: @Spiff, Yes, that works! In the past Touch ID was excruciatingly slow, but I tried it now and it unlocked the screen really fast. It would perhaps be even better if I could disable the "lock your screen" feature of Touch ID (without disabling Touch ID which I would like to keep and while keeping the forced shut down which I also want to keep). I have never had a reason to intentionally lock my screen, so disabling it would spare me a (now shorter) step.

Comment: Good to hear. I'm going to add my suggestion as an Answer in case it ends up being the best suggestion anyone can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Locking the screen when hitting the power button is a power button feature, not a feature of the Touch ID system whose sensor happens to cohabitate with the power button. So disabling Touch ID doesn't disable this power button feature, and Apple doesn't seem to currently provide a way to disable the "lock the screen when the power button is pressed" feature.

One workaround to your problem that works for many people is to make sure they have "Use Touch ID to unlock my Mac" enabled (it's in "Settings > Touch ID & Password"), so if you accidentally hit the power button and lock the screen, you can just tap it again to let Touch ID unlock it again for you.

Comment: Since 'Apple doesn't seem to currently provide a way to disable the "lock the screen when the power button is pressed" feature', then the best and perhaps only solution is the one you proposed, i.e., to unlock the screen using TouchID: much much easier and faster than having to type a password. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

One method for disabling Touch ID is to
disable all the checkboxes in *System Preferences > Touch ID*.

A much more forceful
[method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/268255/452951)
is (applies only to older MacOS versions):

```
cd /System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj
mv PowerButton.nib PowerButton1.nib
```

You can also use PowerKey to remap the power button,
but the press and hold forced shutdown is handled by the
hardware and cannot be disabled by software.

(The above methods are not sure to work, or to keep
on working across operating system updates.)

Comment: That "forceful method" already doesn't work and probably hasn't worked in several years and several major macOS releases. You haven't been able to modify anything under `/System` in ages.

Comment: @Spiff: I couldn't test, but I added this information to my answer. Please check if it's ok now. I'm not on the Mac, so don't know if alternatives such as booting from Live USB work on it.

Comment: if you modify the sealed system volume by any means from outside the running OS, it will refuse to boot & demand you reinstall the OS. There are hacks to re-sign the volume, but they're way above my paygrade. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secd698747c9/web

Comment: @Tetsujin: Understood that Apple is fanatic about its system files. I restricted my answer to older MacOS versions, as I found this advice in a post from about only 6 years ago (more or less).

Comment: Yeah. It's been getting harder & harder since Catalina 2019 & should now be considered 'impossible' for the average user.